# Make Boost Python not delete the C++ object in destructor

Tags: wxwidgets, boost-python

I'm creating bindings for a subset of wxWidgets using Boost Python. Window objects in wxWidgets should not be deleted manually since they handle their own deletion: for example, when a top level window is closed by the user clicking the close button it automatically deletes itself. If a window *is* deleted strange things will happen with event handlers etc.

(Details: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_windowdeletionoverview.html)

This however leads to a problem with window objects created in Python: on garbage collection the C++ object is always deleted!

Is there any way to tell Boost Python to not take ownership of C++ objects it creates? Something like a call policy for the constructor perhaps?

(Also, I'm a little bit worried about how to handle objects deleted from C++. What should happen to the Python object when an associated C++ object is deleted? Python will not get notified about this in any way.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#deleter_constructor) and some setup in Boost.Python.

`boost::shared_ptr` has constructors that accept a custom deleter.  When the `shared_ptr`'s reference count reaches zero, the `shared_ptr` will invoke the customer deleter, passing the previously managed pointer as an argument.  This allows for different deallocation strategies to be used, such as a "no-op", or one that invokes `wxWindow::Destroy()`.

```cpp
class window {};
void no_op(window*) {};
boost::shared_ptr(new window(), &no_op);
```

When exposing a class to Python, Boost.Python allows for types to be managed via a `HeldType`.  In this case, the `HeldType` will be `boost::shared_ptr`.  This allows for proper referencing counting to occur between C++ and Python, and allows for the custom deallocation strategy.

```cpp
boost::python::class_<window, boost::shared_ptr<window>, ...>("Window", ...);
```

The trick to getting these to work together transparently is to:

- Suppress Boost.Python from creating a default initializer (`__init__`).
- Explicitly provide an `__init__` function that will invoke a factory function returning a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter.

---

Here is the a mocked up `window` class that is intended to only be destroyed through the `destroy()` member function.

```cpp
class window
{
...
private:
  ~window();
public:
  void destroy();
};
```

A factory function is defined that will create a reference counted `window` object with a custom deleter.  The custom deleter will invoke `destroy()` on the object when the reference count reaches zero.

```cpp
boost::shared_ptr<window> create_window()
{
  return boost::shared_ptr<window>(
    new window(),
    boost::mem_fn(&window::destroy));
}
```

Finally, use Boost.Python to expose the `window` class, but suppress the default initializer, and transparently replace it with the `create_window` factory function.

```cpp
boost::python::class_<window, boost::shared_ptr<window>, 
                      boost::noncopyable>("Window", python::no_init)
  .def("__init__", python::make_constructor(&create_window));
```

---

Here is a complete example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mem_fn.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup window class.
class window
{
public:
  window(unsigned int id)
    : id_(id)
  {
    std::cout << "window::window() " << id_ << std::endl;
  }
  void action() { std::cout << "window::action() " << id_ << std::endl; }
  void destroy()
  {
    std::cout << "window::destroy() " << id_ << std::endl;
    delete this;
  }
private:
  ~window() { std::cout << "window::~window() " << id_ << std::endl; }
private:
  unsigned int id_;
};

/// @brief Factory function that will create reference counted window
///        objects, that will call window::destroy() when the reference
///        count reaches zero.
boost::shared_ptr<window> create_window(unsigned int id)
{
  return boost::shared_ptr<window>(
    new window(id),
    boost::mem_fn(&window::destroy));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
  namespace python = boost::python;
  // Expose window, that will be managed by shared_ptr, and transparently
  // constructs the window via a factory function to allow for a custom
  // deleter.
  python::class_<window, boost::shared_ptr<window>, 
                 boost::noncopyable>("Window", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", python::make_constructor(&create_window))
    .def("action", &window::action)
    ;
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> from example import Window
>>> w1 = Window(1)
window::window() 1
>>> w2 = Window(2)
window::window() 2
>>> w3 = Window(3)
window::window() 3
>>> del w2
window::destroy() 2
window::~window() 2
>>> w3 = None
window::destroy() 3
window::~window() 3
>>> w = w1
>>> del w1
>>> w.action()
window::action() 1
>>> w = None
window::destroy() 1
window::~window() 1
```

Notice how Python only informs C++ to delete the object once Python no longer has a reference to the instance.  Thus, in this scenario, Python will not try to interact on an object that has been deleted.  Hopefully this alleviates concerns expressed when an object is deleted in C++.

If there are situations where C++ will be deleting objects that are still active in Python, then consider using an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to separate the implementation class and the handle class.  The handle class could check if the associated implementation instance has been deleted before forwarding the call, allowing an exception to be thrown up to Python.

Comment: Wow, thanks, lots of good ideas there. I came up with another solution, creating a static factory method for each class that returns an object with return_value_policy reference_existing_object. But your solution is better.

Comment: I have tried this approach with an abstract class but I found that make_constructor does not seem to work then. If I use an init<> constructor it works, but if I use make_constructor the implementations of the virtual methods are lost when passed back and forth between Python and C++. Since there's no way to set a custom destructor with init<> I've derived a custom shared_ptr class from shared_ptr that always has a custom destructor. But I'm not sure its safe to derive from shared_ptr. What do you think?

Comment: I would be hesitant to derive from `shared_ptr`.  Conceptually, it should be okay when used in a non-polymorpic manner.  However, Boost.Python does a fair amount of meta-programming and handling for `shared_ptr`, so I cannot say with certainty that it is safe.  The original problem sounds like the result of object slicing.  I expect a Boost.Python solution is possible with a mix of [`bases`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#bases-spec) and [`wrapper`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/wrapper.html).

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a much simpler solution by using auto_ptr, and it's even in the [Boost Python FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#ownership). There are more details on the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#ownership_of_C.2B-.2B-_object). So far its working perfectly.

Comment: Please avoid auto_ptr